# How to set authorization scopes for box?

Tags: authorization, box-api

Does anyone know how to specify specific authorization scopes for box?  My only option seems to be in the OAuth2 parameters section, with one simple check box asking for scope to read and write all files and folders.  In the authorization doc it displays different scopes in their screen shot but does not detail how to request them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We currently only support the single read/write across the entire account scope, though we'll be adding more over time.

Comment: If you have a request for a specific scope, please let us know at api AT box dot com.